# CSS and images do not appear until my application makes a database call

Tags: laravel-4, cloud9-ide

I'm hoping this isn't a double-post - I couldn't find my issue in the search, but I imagine it might be asked in several ways.  My project involves a **PHP5 workspace** running the Laravel 4 framework.

Quickly, my issue occurs when I access any webpage within my private project that does not first make a call to a database.  When viewing the page, my images are missing and the CSS styles - though correctly called in source, and accessible when I click on the HREF's for my styles - aren't displayed properly.

After going to a page that makes a database call (for instance, my Manage Users page which displays a list of users in the database), all images and styles in all pages work.  Essentially, I:

1. Access the homepage, which is static HTML.  It's styles are broken.
2. Access an admin panel page which is static HTML.  It's styles are broken.
3. Access an admin panel page that pulls a list of users to the database.  The styles suddenly work.
4. Any pages I visit after this point display styles properly.

Has this happened to anyone else?  Is there a simple way to resolve this?

Comment: well this sure sounds really weird....can you post some code for us to see....right now the only thing that comes to me is - what do you mean by broken styles ? Is the page structure broken or do the style sheets dont load at all ?

Comment: @rizwaniqbal - The issue was that the requests I pass over SSL break the stylesheets.  Requests passed over http display just fine.